# html5 geoLocation error in desktop PCs

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am suffering from a very weird issue. I am using modern browsers' built in feature to ask users for their location. This works well in laptops, tablets and mobile browsers. However, geolocation is way off when the feature is used from a desktop PC. Even when connected to the same router, desktop PC shows results that are way off (over 100 km).

I tested my script on other desktop PCs and the same problem. All desktop PCs (that are in different locations) point to one particular coordinate.

Geolocation is very accurate on laptops, tablets and mobile devices. Really don't know what's causing this. I am using same browser for the laptop and the desktop.

Comment: Could be the problem is with the browser you are using on desktop.

Comment: @Gandalf it's the latest browser and the version is same as the one i use for the laptop. Also I have tested this in multiple PCs with different browsers.

Comment: Desktop PCs do not have a GPS device, like some laptops, and most tablets and mobile devices, so you are not going to get an accurate location.

Comment: @PatrickEvans hmm that means big problem for my script :/

Answer (score 2):

Desktop PCs rarely have GPS ;) so the browser automatically reverts to using even GeoIP:

GeoIP only has a VERY limited accuracy because it depends on the location of the IP and your internet IP (the only one known to have any geolocation) is where your ISP is located.